# How can i get the email of a paid order with the prestashop 1.6.0.11 webservice

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop-1.6

Im using the prestashop 1.6.0.11 webservice and I need to know when a payment is accepted and then get the email of that user. I cant find nothing about that in the prestashop documentation.

i've activated the "orders" and "order_payments" resource with (GET)(PUT)(POST)(DELETE)(HEAD) in the webservice configuration option but i dont know how to get it with the api.

I can get the email from the Mysql Db with a query like this:

```
SELECT c.email
FROM ps_customer AS c
LEFT JOIN ps_orders AS o ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
LEFT JOIN ps_order_payment AS p ON o.reference = p.order_reference
WHERE  p.order_reference = "JTAGSRWCH"
```

But i dont think is a good idea to work directly with the db.